# Heavy load while transfering images via socket.io over websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to stream images from one client to another over a NodeJS-based backend. I send an image every 40ms to the backend which in return emits the image to another client. My problem is, that every client pair increases the load by 5% on the backend. Each image is about 20KB.

My frontend code looks like this:

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000');
const fs = require('fs');

socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.emit('room', '123456');
});

socket.on('joined', () => {
    console.log('joined the room');
    const file = fs.readFileSync('./1902865_597805016961665_1536612023_n.jpg');

    setInterval(() => {
        socket.emit('frame', file);
    }, 40);
});
```

The backend looks like this:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('room', function (room) {
        console.log(`got join request for ${room}`);
        socket.join(room);
        socket.myroom = room;
        socket.emit('joined');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        socket.to(socket.myroom).emit('disconnected');
        socket.disconnect();
    });

    socket.frameCounter = 0;
    socket.on('frame', frame => {
        console.dir(`frameCounter ${socket.frameCounter}`);
        socket.frameCounter += 1;
        socket.to(socket.myroom).emit('frame', frame);
    });
});
```

A working example can be found here: https://code.flyacts.com/tsc/socket-io-performance-problems/

Is this expected behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?